# Why I don't see properties of the response class on the client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I use .net core 5 in my project.

I have this api method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<NumberValidationResponse> CheckNumberAsync(String number)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _service.someMethodn(number);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(ex.InnerException.ToString());  //write to file or database
            return new NumberValidationResponse(null, false, "An error occurred, contact administrator.");
        }
    }
```

As you can see the return type of the API method is Task.

Here is NumberValidationResponse definition:

```
    public class NumberValidationResponse : BaseResponse
    {
        private string Number { get; set; }
        private bool Success { get; set; }

        public NumberValidationResponse(string number, bool isPositive, string message) : base(message) 
        {
            Number = number;
            Success = isPositive;
        }
    }

    public abstract class BaseResponse
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public BaseResponse(string message)
        {
            Message = message;
        }
    }
```

The `_service.someMethod` in CheckNumberAsync returns NumberValidationResponse type with values of number, success, and message.
The same values I expect to see on the client, but in the client, I see only value of the message property.

Why I see only the message value of the NumberValidationResponse class and don't see other properties of this class in the client?

Comment: it maybe a typo - but your constructor and type in `catch` block is `PhoneNumberValidationResponse()` but class name is `NumberValidationResponse()`. If that's not the issue - there got to be something more... otherwise, full NumberValidationResponse comes to the client

Answer (score 1):

Change `Number` and `Success` from **private** to **public**.

Private members don't get serialised into the response by default.